# Sending email attachments failes from Gnus or Mutt, but works from Gmail and Evolution

Tags: email, gmail, mutt, evolution, gnus

When I send an email via Gnus or Mutt, attachments are (on the receiving end) either missing or truncated to 0 bytes. Sending from Gmail's Web interface and from Evolution works correctly.

This is annoying, as I prefer the text-based clients.

Comment: Are you sending to the same email address when the attachments are missing or truncated to 0 bytes as when you send from Gmail and Evolution? Are you attaching the same files? E.g., if you attach a test text file and send it via mutt to the same address that can receive attachments via Gmail what happens? Are you always sending to a particular email service, e.g., always to hotmail or gmail addresses or does this happen with messages sent to many different email services?

Comment: I am always sending to my own email account (gmail); sometimes to an MS Exchange account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both clients were misconfigured. Gnus had a `~/.gnus` file that caused each email to be truncated to its headers prior to sending (misplaced `ad-do-it` in a `defadvice`), and `mutt` was not able to send mail at all.